# Native query on hibernate is not working (unexpected token)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hsqldb, hibernate-native-query

I'm coding this query using hibernate. But it is not working. Seems the alias c is unknown.
Some one knows what is the problem?

```
static final  String BEGIN_QUERY = "SELECT c.contratoId, c.contrato, c.classificacao, c.responsavel, c.uf, c.sigla,"
        + "c.statusContrato, c.fornecedor, c.site, c.login, c.senha, c.telefone, c.cnpj, c.codigoFornecedor, c.hidrometro"
        + "c.nome, c.endereco, c.despesa, c.descricao, c.mp, c.status, c.estadoLancamento"
        + "h.historicoId, h.dataCobranca, h.dataVencimento, h.dataEmissao, h.dataLancamento, h.dataCompensacao, h.dataAtualizacao, h.docPgt, h.docCompensacao"
        + "FROM Contrato c, Historico h"
        + "WHERE c.contratoId = h.contratoId"
        + "AND 1=1";
```

**THE EXCEPTION:**

```
    Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: C
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSelect(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
... 19 more
```

Comment: You are missing some space characters, the end of your query looks like : `h.docCompensacaoFROM Contrato c, Historico hWHERE c.contratoId = h.contratoIdAND 1=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed several spaces and commas

```
static final  String BEGIN_QUERY = "SELECT c.contratoId, c.contrato, c.classificacao, c.responsavel, c.uf, c.sigla, "
        + "c.statusContrato, c.fornecedor, c.site, c.login, c.senha, c.telefone, c.cnpj, c.codigoFornecedor, c.hidrometro, " // here
        + "c.nome, c.endereco, c.despesa, c.descricao, c.mp, c.status, c.estadoLancamento, " // here
        + "h.historicoId, h.dataCobranca, h.dataVencimento, h.dataEmissao, h.dataLancamento, h.dataCompensacao, h.dataAtualizacao, h.docPgt, h.docCompensacao " // here 
        + "FROM Contrato c, Historico h " // here
        + "WHERE c.contratoId = h.contratoId " // and here
        + "AND 1=1";
```